# unstability of a scroll 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For the purposes of this question I will work over $\mathbb{C}$.  Consider on $T=\mathbb{P}^1$ the bundle $E=O_{T}^{\oplus 3}\oplus O_T(-1)^{\oplus 2}$ and $\mathbb{P}E_T$ the associated projective bundle on $T$. Let $[s,t]$ be coordinates on $T$. Let $w_0,w_1,w_2$ be a frame for $O_T^{\oplus 3}$ and $u_4,u_5$ sections of $O_T(-1)^2$ with poles at $s=0$. Set $w_4=su_4$, $w_5=su_5$, and let $X\subset \mathbb{P}E$ be the scroll given by the vanishing of the rank 2 minors of 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{}
w_1 & w_2 & w_4\\
w_0 & w_1 & w_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Given $t\in T$, does there exist $m$ such that the $m$-Hilbert point of $X_t$ is not stable for the action of $SL$ on $H^0(X_t,O_{\mathbb{P}E}(1)|_{X_t})$?

Comment: Hi Carlo,  This question should still be improved.  You are answering Tim's comment at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28037/ but it would be much better to post a complete, self-contained question.  You should look over the FAQ again: try to make the title into a question, etc.  Also, I'll try to clean up the TeX, but I don't know what `\frd` is supposed to be (googling didn't turn anything up).

Comment: While cleaning up the TeX, I also made some grammar changes to try to put everything into sentences.  This, of course, required guessing some of the meaning --- syntax is part of semantics.  If I made an error, please roll back, and I apologize.  I just guessed that `\frd` in `\mathbb{P}E\frd T` was supposed to make the `T` a subscript, and so I replaced it with an underscore `_` protected by back-ticks.  It takes some getting used to writing TeX here on MO, because you really should protect every TeX command with back-ticks, so that MarkDown doesn't process it before jsMath gets a chance.